# regex number of repetitions from code

Tags: python, regex

Can you use values from script to inform regexs dynamically how to operate?

For example:

```
base_pattern = r'\s*(([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+)'
n_rep = random.randint(1, 9)
new_pattern = base_pattern + '{n_rep}'
line_matches = re.findall(new_pattern, some_text)
```

I keep getting problems with trying to get the grouping to work

---

### Explanation

I am attempting to find the most common number of repetitions of a regex pattern in a text file in order to find table type data within files.
I have the idea to make a regex such as this:

```
base_pattern = r'\s*(([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+)'
line_matches = np.array([re.findallbase_pattern, line) for line_num, line in enumerate(some_text.split("\n"))])

# Find where the text has similar number of words/data in each line
where_same_pattern= np.where(np.diff([len(x) for x in line_matches])==0)
line_matches_where_same = line_matches[where_same_pattern]

# Extract out just the lines which have data
interesting_lines = np.array([x for x in line_matches_where_same if x != []])

# Find how many words in each line of interest
len_of_lines = [len(l) for l in interesting_lines]

# Use the most prevalent as the most likely number of columns of data
n_cols = Counter(len_of_lines).most_common()[0][0]


# Rerun the data through a regex to find the columns
new_pattern = base_pattern + '{n_cols}'
line_matches = np.array([re.findall(new_pattern, line) for line_num, line in enumerate(some_text.split("\n"))])
```

Comment: Use `n_cols` as shown in the answers below: `new_pattern = base_pattern + '{'+n_rep+'}'`. Also, `\h` is not supported in Python, use `\s` (replace `[ \h]` with `\s`). And `\w` includes `\d`, you can replace `[\d.\w]` with `[\w.]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is just a string. So, all you need is to convert your number into a string. You can use `format` (for example, https://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python/web/new-str-format.html) to do that:

```
base_pattern = r'\s*(([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+)'
n_rep = random.randint(1, 9)
new_pattern = base_pattern + '{{{0}}}'.format(n_rep)
print new_pattern ## '\\s*(([\\d.\\w]+)[ \\h]+){6}'
```

Note that the two first and the two last curly braces are creating the curly braces in the new pattern, while `{0}` is being replaced by the number `n_rep`

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the value of the variable, not a string literal with the name of the variable, e.g.:

```
new_pattern = base_pattern + '{' + n_cols + '}'
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think that through very well before I threw it up there.  However, I did try this and it still isn't getting the same output as if I were to repeat the regex explicitly.  Hence `'\s*((([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+){6}([\d.\w]+)[ \h]*)'` <> `r'\s*([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+([\d.\w]+)[ \h]+([\d.\w]+)[ \h]*'`

Comment: the 2 are not equivalent, you have `[ \h]*` instead of `+` in the second regex